# Can coefficients of a weight enumerator ever be non-unimodal?

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, finite-fields, coding-theory

Let C be a linear code and W(C) its weight enumerator with $W(C)=1+a_dx^d+...+a_{n-d}x^{n-d}+a_nx^n.$
Computations always show that the a_i's are ascending up to the middle (then descending). My question is if this is a necessary condition? If yes, how can it be proved? Or does anyone have a counter example?

Answer (score 5):

Counterexample: Take the binary linear code with the generator matrix
$$\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1\end{pmatrix}.$$
The number of codewords of weights 1..5 is [2, 1, 1, 2, 1].